# Index out of range exception was unhandled in c# (creating binary search tree with two traversals)

Tags: c#

I can't find the problem with this code,it says that: Index was outside the bounds of the array in this section:

```
Node node = new Node(postorder[iterator]);
```

Here is the code:

```
public Node reQ_buildTreeUtil(int[] inorder, int[] postorder, int start ,int end, int iterator)
{
    //base case 
    if (start > end)
        return null;

    Node node = new Node(postorder[iterator]);
    iterator--;

    if (start == end)
        return node;

    int index_in_Inorder = index_search(inorder, start,node.value);

    node.right = reQ_buildTreeUtil(inorder, postorder, index_in_Inorder + 1, end, iterator);
    node.left = reQ_buildTreeUtil(inorder, postorder, start ,index_in_Inorder - 1, iterator);

    return node;
}

public Node buildTree(int[] inorder, int[] postorder)
{
    int n = vinorder.Length;
    int iterator = n - 1;

    return reQ_buildTreeUtil(inorder, postorder, 0, n - 1, iterator);
}

int index_search(int[] array,int start, int x)
{
    int i;
    for ( i = start;i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == x)
            break;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but perhaps the index is outside the bounds of the array? Maybe you should put in some checks to ensure that it is not so?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Where are `niza` and `n` declared?

Comment: If you have tried to run this in the debugger, you might have observed `iterator == -1` at the crash site. I don't understand what the code is meant to accomplish -- can you provide an example of expected input and output?

Your `index_search` method returns the size of the input array if the value is not found -- is this intentional?

Comment: i have two text boxes where the inputs are: 
3,5,7,10,13,15,17,20,21,25,28,30,26,40,45 (inorder traversal) 
3,7,5,13,17,15,10,21,28,25,36,45,40,30,20 (postorder) 
and based on these,i  need to get 
20 10 5 3 7 15 13 17 30 25 21 28 40 36 45  
on the third textbox.I tried the same code in java,works perfectly

Comment: index_search method returns the index of the root in inorder array,

Comment: Can you post the code that is calling `buildTree`? Also, is `vinorder` a typo?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you try to access the array called postorder using an index (iterator) which is out of bounds. I suggest you debug your code and let it run until you get the exception where it will break. Then you can trace backwards using the call stack window, to see the variable values in each recursive call, and try to understand why this happens.